# Generate a swagger file from unknown objects (.net)

Tags: reflection, swagger, dynamics-crm, reflection.emit, swagger-codegen

I want to develop a new API. It must connect a Dynamics CRM and front developers.

Today, the developed "workaround" is :

1. Fill an Excel file to describe the CRM and custom objects (with fetchXml, ...)
2. Write and concatenate strings to write a YAML file.
3. Copy this file to swagger editor and make tests with Postman

In a first step, I want to generate the schema without strings concatenations... (temporarily, waiting to replace the Excel file with OData and ASP.NET Core to have something more powerful)

For the moment, I use reflection to build my objects from the Excel file:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
...

var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Module");
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(entity.CrmEntityName);
foreach (var attribute in entity.Attributes)
{
    Type t = typeof(int);
    switch (attribute.DataType.ToLower())
    {
        case "string":
            t = typeof(string);
            break;
        case "integer":
            t = typeof(int);
            break;
        case "date":
            t = typeof(DateTime);
            break;
    }
    typeBuilder.DefineField(attribute.CrmName, t.GetType(), FieldAttributes.Public);
    var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    // create the Swagger models here
}
```

How can I generate my swagger from these types and properties? 
I've view an object named `Schema` which contains a name and another `Schema`, I don't know if is a wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement and register a IDocumentFilter in which you can register the custom types that you've created with TypeBuilder.

```
public class MyDocFilter : Swashbuckle.Swagger.IDocumentFilter
{
  public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
  {
    schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(MyDynamicType);
  }
}
```

Make sure to register it in the SwaggerConfig like this:

```
c.DocumentFilter<MyDocFilter>();
```

The custom types should then appear in the "definitions" section of the Swagger document.
Now, if you have a generic OData GET method that appears multiple times in the Swagger document (one for each of the custom types) and you want each of those to display a proper Response type then you should also modify the paths of the SwaggerDocument something like:

```
public class MyDocFilter : Swashbuckle.Swagger.IDocumentFilter
{
  public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
  {
    foreach (string path in swaggerDoc.paths.Keys)
    {
      System.Type mytype = null; // Create custom type...
      schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(mytype);

      var response = swaggerDoc.paths[path].get.responses["200"];
      if (response.schema == null)
        response.schema = new Schema();
      response.schema.@ref = "#/definitions/" + mytype.Name;
    }
  }
}
```